# Unable to edit tables in Sybase PowerDesigner

Tags: database, powerdesigner

I created a table name Academics for a School. Then I have added a attribute as Course Name in Academics table.

But when I am trying to edit the Academics table, I am not able to open the properties of Academics table.

Comment: "table" goes with Physical Model, while "attribute" goes with Object-Oriented Model. Is it table/column or class/attribute?

Comment: How are you trying to edit the "table"? Where do you click? Do you have any error message?
Is it in the same PowerDesigner session, or did you save the model, close it, reopen it... or reopen PowerDesigner?

Comment: I am clicking on the exiting table. I am not able to open the properties of the exiting table to add new attributes

Comment: I don't see how it is possible. Can you post an image of your PowerDesigner environment, just to understand?